# Show partial differentiation in a proper way in LaTeX

Tags: derivatives, notation

I have an assignment where I've have to use partial differentiation, however, I'm unsure whether this would be the correct way to show it using LaTeX. You can see the equation below.
$$\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(xy+\cos(2x+y)\right)\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y-2\sin(2 x+y)\right)=1-2\cos(2 x+y)$$

What I'm unsure about is whether I can use the $\Rightarrow$, between the lines - is that true in mathematics, or should I use $\Updownarrow$? Furthermore, would you show it like this, or would you show it differently?

Comment: I am new to StackExchange, may I ask why this question have gotten voted to -3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather write it as (by using split-environment):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(xy+\cos(2x+y)\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[y-2\sin(2 x+y)\right]=1-2\cos(2 x+y)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for the answer, may I ask, why you want to use the squared brackets?

Comment: I try to use square brackets to indicate that there is an operator involved or to make it look better because $(((x+y))))$ is just an overkill of the same bracket :D.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help, I really appreciate it :)